# Update MySQL table with records from local file

Tags: mysql, delphi, firedac

**What I'm trying to do**
I have a JSON file with some records. I want to update a MySQL table (same structure) with those records. Basically, a one-way-sync.
I understand there may be various approaches here. What I'm looking for is one where I can leave as much of the process as possible to FireDAC. For simplicity, I would like to avoid SQL statements, iterating over records or using literal field names etc.
(This is a *Delphi 10.4* console application)

**What I tried but couldn't get to work**
I tried using a TFDQuery to load the entire MySQL table, then merge the resulting dataset using `LoadFromFile()`:

```
fdQuery := TFDQuery.Create(nil);
fdQuery.Connection := fdConnection;
fdQuery.Open('SELECT * FROM mysqltable');

fdQuery.ResourceOptions.StoreMergeData := dmDataMerge;
fdQuery.LoadFromFile('C:\localfile\myjson.json');
```

This looks good so far. If I look at the dataset's contents...

```
fdQuery.First();
repeat
  WriteLn(fdQuery.GetRow().DumpRow(False));
  fdQuery.Next();
until fdQuery.EoF;
```

...I neatly see all records, appended or updated with what's in the file.

**The problem is** I cannot get this 'state' back into the MySQL table. It seems I cannot call `Post()` or `ApplyUpdates()` etc. and upon closing the `fdQuery`, whatever was added or modified from the JSON file just gets discarded.

**My question is:** What am I doing wrong on this approach? I suppose I could use `TFDBatchMove` instead but I would like to understand whether or how the above approach could be made to work.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/1362-firedac-querymergedataset-how-to-use/) can be helpful..

Comment: In addition to what @whosrdaddy his suggested, you might take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33354428/firedac-equivalent-of-dbexpress-briefcase-model.

Comment: Btw, unless your Json records contain the necessary state (delta) information for an ApplyUpdates to be possible, probably the best you can do is to do a manual Locate/Edit/Post/ApplyUpdates against your MySql table.  At least that way you get the opportunity to determine exactly which record(s) get updated from each Json one.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs; whosrdaddy's suggestion already allowed a succesful record insert into the table but updates/modifications don't seem to work yet. I'm trying to further isolate the issue atm.